# getting default value of dropdown box html in php loop

Tags: php, html, arrays, drop-down-menu

So I have this problem, which I don't see how it's happening. Basically I have 2 arrays one of which has a list of apparatus and the other just has one apparatus that the user can operate. I want to have a dropdown list of all the apparatus avliable, but the default value that is selected is the one that they can operate (They can only operate one at a time) Here is the code, and I have an if statement to check if the user can operate it and selected = "selected" but that doesn't seem to be working (In firefox)... Any help would be great.

Thanks!

```
 <?php
                            foreach ($apparatuslist as $apparatus):?>
                            <option value="<?php echo $apparatus['apparatus'];?>" <?php if ($driveron['apparatus'] == $apparatus['apparatus']){echo "SELECTED";} ?> ><?php echo substr($apparatus['apparatus'], 5); ?></option>


                            <?php endforeach;?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have it right in your question, but not in your code

```
<?php
    foreach ($apparatuslist as $apparatus):?>
    <option value="<?php echo $apparatus['apparatus'];?>" <?php if ($driveron['apparatus'] == $apparatus['apparatus']){echo "selected=\"selected\"";} ?> ><?php echo substr($apparatus['apparatus'], 5); ?></option>
<?php endforeach;?>
```

Should do the trick..

Comment: Hmm weird... I thought I had selected = selected in my code... maybe I just missed it

Answer (score 1):

The code is correct. It's optional whether you write select="selected" or jus "selected" that doesn't effect firefox.The code is correct but not working means the problem in browser i guess. Either it is cache problem as newer version of firefox has cache problem or there may be other kind of problem in firefox. Please check in other computer's firefox.

Answer (score 0):

correct syntax is: `selected="selected"` in OPTION tag